# Has Iran threatened to leave the Nuclear Non-Proliferation Treaty before?

Tags: iran, nuclear-weapons, treaty, proliferation

[News](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20200121-us-decries-iran-threat-to-withdraw-from-global-nuclear-treaty/) is that

> Iranian Foreign Minister Javad Zarif said on Monday that Tehran would withdraw from the Non-Proliferation Treaty (NPT) if Europeans continued with what he called “their improper behaviour” or referred Iran to the UN Security Council over its alleged violations of the 2015 deal.

Has Iran threatened to leave the NPT before today? (As an aside, North Korea [has](https://www.armscontrol.org/factsheets/dprkchron)  threatened to leave in 1993 although it didn't do it then, but eventually did in 2003.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Iran previously threatened withdrawal from the NNPT in 2018.

See, for example, https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/apr/24/iran-threatens-to-withdraw-from-nuclear-weapons-treaty-npt

Comment: Reading that article it seems they threatened to do so if the JCPOA is "scrapped", so it is more or less the same threat they reiterated yesterday.

Comment: Yes.  Is that not what you were looking for when you asked "Has Iran threatened to leave the NPT before today?"

Comment: It was a bit of an open question. I guess I can ask something more focused separately given what I know now.